# Can't we iterate over integer using map in python?

Tags: python

Here, in line *ans = list(map(int, num))* it's returning int object is not iterable. Can't we just change int number to list using map?

```
def plusOne(self, digits: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        # arr = [str(x) for x in digits]
        arr = list(map(str, digits))
        word = ''
        word = word.join(arr)
        num = int(word)
        num1 = num + 1
        ans = list(map(int, num))
        return ans
```

Comment: Change it to _what_ list? It's unclear what you're expecting to happen.

Comment: num = 123 , i want to make it [1, 2, 3]

Comment: The entire point of `map()` is to apply a function to a collection of items.  If you don't have a collection, why are you even using `map()`?

Comment: No, you can't. Numbers aren't iterable. You can however use division/modulus to do the math to break the number down into its digits, or convert the number to a string and iterate the sub-strings representing the digits.

Comment: Well given that's the result of joining the digits to start with, don't you already have that list?

Comment: `arr = list(map(str, digit))` <- is there a typo here? I don't see `digit` defined elsewhere.

Comment: yea, got it, i need to change list to int, add 1 to it and change again back to list,

Comment: `digit` is undefined.  This code cannot produce the claimed error.

Comment: Okay, resolved. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No map changes each element of a iterable. Integers are not iterable.

This can be achieved like this:

```
list(str(124))
```

Comment: If the OP wants a list of ints, then you may need to: `list(map(int, str(124)))` or `[int(x) for x in str(124)]`.